# "The Transport Protocol thread failed" – "The socket is EOF" with J2SSH connection using Java

Tags: java, ssh, ssh-keys, j2ssh

I am trying to establish an SSH connection through my Java code, but getting below exception .. I tested my connection through Putty/Winscp tools and it works fine. The problem is with my Java code...

```
SEVERE: The Transport Protocol thread failed
java.io.IOException: The socket is EOF
    at com.sshtools.j2ssh.transport.TransportProtocolInputStream.readBufferedData(Unknown Source)
    at com.sshtools.j2ssh.transport.TransportProtocolInputStream.readMessage(Unknown Source)
    at com.sshtools.j2ssh.transport.TransportProtocolCommon.readMessage(Unknown Source)
    at com.sshtools.j2ssh.transport.kex.DhGroup1Sha1.performClientExchange(Unknown Source)
    at com.sshtools.j2ssh.transport.TransportProtocolClient.performKeyExchange(Unknown Source)
    at com.sshtools.j2ssh.transport.TransportProtocolCommon.beginKeyExchange(Unknown Source)
    at com.sshtools.j2ssh.transport.TransportProtocolCommon.onMsgKexInit(Unknown Source)
    at com.sshtools.j2ssh.transport.TransportProtocolCommon.startBinaryPacketProtocol(Unknown Source)
    at com.sshtools.j2ssh.transport.TransportProtocolCommon.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Below is my piece of Java code to establish the connection

```
public class MySSHClient {

  static SshClient ssh = null;
  static SshConnectionProperties properties = null;
  SessionChannelClient session = null;

  private static void MySSHClient(String hostName, String userName, String passwd )
  {

    try
    {
      // Make a client connection
      ssh = new SshClient();
      properties = new SshConnectionProperties();
      properties.setHost("192.168.1.175");

      // Connect to the host
      ssh.connect(properties, new IgnoreHostKeyVerification());

      // Create a password authentication instance
      PasswordAuthenticationClient pwd = new PasswordAuthenticationClient();

      pwd.setUsername("root");
      pwd.setPassword("123456");

      // Try the authentication
      int result = ssh.authenticate(pwd);

      // Evaluate the result
      if (result==AuthenticationProtocolState.COMPLETE) {

        System.out.println("Connection Authenticated");
      }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
      System.out.println("Exception : " + e.getMessage());
    }

  }//end of method.


  public String execCmd(String cmd)
  {
    String theOutput = "";
    try
    {
      // The connection is authenticated we can now do some real work!
      session = ssh.openSessionChannel();

      if ( session.executeCommand(cmd) )
      {
        IOStreamConnector output = new IOStreamConnector();
        java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream bos =  new
        java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream();
        output.connect(session.getInputStream(), bos );
        session.getState().waitForState(ChannelState.CHANNEL_CLOSED);
        theOutput = bos.toString();
      }
      //else
      //throw Exception("Failed to execute command : " + cmd);
      //System.out.println("Failed to execute command : " + cmd);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
      System.out.println("Exception : " + e.getMessage());
    }

    return theOutput;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args){
      MySSHClient(null, null, null);
    }
```

Comment: try using http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/

Comment: to be honest, the exception and the posted code do not seem to match, also `execCmd` is not used.

Comment: what is the version of `ssh` on the linux host?

Comment: [root@centos-test ssh]# ssh -v localhost
OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to localhost [::1] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/identity type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/identity-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version

Comment: There are several answers for your question here – please accept one (if it answers your question) so that your question stops from showing up as _unanswered_ in the question searches.

Answer (score 15):

## Motivation

I stumbled across this question and answers while investigating the error in question `java.io.IOException: The socket is EOF`. Because changing the code to use some other SSH Java library is not immediately possible in my case and the stated explanation by @a3.14_Infinity was not detailed enough for me, I'd like to add my take on it.

## java.io.IOException: The socket is EOF - Why?

Because this exception is not very helpful, I first tried [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) to see what's going on over the wire, but to no avail. So I configured the `sshd_config` (OpenSSH 6.9) to log on `DEBUG3` level and got the answer in the `/var/log/auth.log` file of my test machine. It stated a ***fatal error*** while trying to negotiate the key exchange algorithm with the SSH client (the Java SSH library).

Because the SSH server and client could not agree on a mutual key exchange algorithm the OpenSSH server terminates the connection to the client. In consequence, the Java SSH library code throws the exception.

## But why does it happen?

The `sshtools.j2ssh` ([sshtools : j2ssh-core : 0.2.9](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Csshtools%7Cj2ssh-core%7C0.2.9%7Cjar)) library code is pretty old and discontinued. Starting with [OpenSSH 6.7](http://www.openssh.com/txt/release-6.7) (released October, 2014) default ciphers and MAC have been altered to remove unsafe algorithms which includes the `blowfish-cbc` cipher. And with [OpenSSH 6.9](http://www.openssh.com/txt/release-6.9) (released June, 2015) the support for the 1024-bit `diffie-hellman-group1-sha1` key exchange is disabled by default.

When you still use the prehistoric SSH Tools `j2ssh` library (God forbid) connecting to a newer OpenSSH server you will get the described error. The library code only offers the `diffie-hellman-group1-sha1` key exchange algorithm to the OpenSSH server which it does not support by default. Thus, a secure connection cannot be established.

## Cannot change the code?

If moving to another Java SSH library is not immediately possible (my case) then you can re-enable the disabled `diffie-hellman-group1-sha1` key exchange algorithm in the OpenSSH's server config file `sshd_config`. For example like this.

```
Ciphers aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,blowfish-cbc

KexAlgorithms diffie-hellman-group1-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
```

But let me be clear on this. The `diffie-hellman-group1-sha1` key exchange algorithm as well as the `blowfish-cbc` cipher are turned off by default because they are insecure. Reenabling them should only be a temporary measure until you can replace this obsolete Java SSH library.

<s>Finally, I like to point out that the suggested *Java Secure Channel (JSch)* library in other answers is discontinued. So, you might want to consider [sshj](https://github.com/hierynomus/sshj) or even [ssh2j-maverick](https://github.com/sshtools/j2ssh-maverick) instead.</s>

**Edit:  I was wrong**, the *Java Secure Channel [JSch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch)* library is alive (JSCH 0.1.54 was released on 2016-09-03 [on MavenCentral](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22com.jcraft%22%20AND%20a%3A%22jsch%22)) and certainly worth your consideration. Alternatively, you may want to consider also [sshj](https://github.com/hierynomus/sshj) or [ssh2j-maverick](https://github.com/sshtools/j2ssh-maverick).

## Addendum: Migration

To keep the migration effort for the `sshtools.j2ssh` ([sshtools : j2ssh-core : 0.2.9](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Csshtools%7Cj2ssh-core%7C0.2.9%7Cjar)) library minimal I looked at the ***commercial*** legacy SSH client library from [SSHTOOLS](https://www.sshtools.com/en/products/java-ssh-client) (version 1.7.1). This allowed to keep the existing library integration code with few minor changes regarding library API and exception handling. Thus, if you do not want to restart from scratch then biting the bullet and sticking with SSHTOOLS is probably your best option. Finally, to gauge the migration effort I first replaced the library with SSHTOOLS' open source library [ssh2j-maverick](https://github.com/sshtools/j2ssh-maverick) which almost has the same API as its latest commercial version (version 1.7.1).

Answer (score 1):

This error (*"The  Transport Protocol thread failed. java.io.IOException: The socket is EOF”*) occurs when j2ssh.jar file is not compatible with current SSH version of SFTP server.

You can try using Java Secure Channel (JSch) from [here](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/).

Courtesy: http://techydiary.com/the-transport-protocol-thread-failed-java-io-ioexception-the-socket-is-eof/

Comment: Thanks Infinity, I will try using JSCH.

Comment: @KarthickSambanghi: Glad that it helped. Later you can accept this answer :)

Answer (score 1):

The following sample Code may help you,

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;


import com.jcraft.jsch.Channel;
import com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelExec;
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSch;
import com.jcraft.jsch.Session;


public class SSHClient {

    /**
     * Constant EXCUTE_CHANNEL
     */
    public static final String EXCUTE_CHANNEL = "exec";

    /**
     * Constant STRICT_KEY_CHECKING
     */
    public static final String STRICT_KEY_CHECKING = "StrictHostKeyChecking";


    /** Name/ip of the remote machine/device **/ 
    private String host;
    private String userName;
    private String password;

    /**
     * This method used to initilze user and host
     * 
     * @param userName
     * @param password
     * @param host
     */
    public SSHClient(String userName,String password, String host) {
        super();
        this.userName = userName;
        this.password = password;
        this.host = host;
    }

    /**
     * This method used to execute commands remotly by using SSHV2
     * 
     * @param host
     * @param username
     * @param password
     * @param command
     * @return
     */
    public String executeCommand(String command) { 
        StringBuilder log = new StringBuilder();
        String response = null;
        Channel channel = null;
        Session session = null;

        try {
            JSch jsch = new JSch();
            JSch.setConfig(STRICT_KEY_CHECKING, Constants.NO);

            session = jsch.getSession(userName, host, 22);


            // If two machines have SSH passwordless logins setup, the following
            // line is not needed:
            session.setPassword(password);
            session.connect();

            channel = session.openChannel(EXCUTE_CHANNEL);
            ((ChannelExec) channel).setCommand(command);

            // channel.setInputStream(System.in);
            channel.setInputStream(null);

            ((ChannelExec) channel).setErrStream(System.err);

            InputStream in = channel.getInputStream();

            channel.connect();

            response = IOUtils.toString(in);

        } catch (Exception ex) {
                //handle exception
        } finally {
            try {
                if (session != null) {
                    session.disconnect();
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                //handle exception
            }
            try {
                if (channel != null) {
                    channel.disconnect();
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                //handle exception
            }

        }
        System.ou.println( "Response received :"+  response));
        return response;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code reused from some google source -

```
import ch.ethz.ssh2.Connection;
import ch.ethz.ssh2.StreamGobbler;
```

```
Connection conn = new Connection(server);
conn.connect();
boolean isAuthenticated = conn.authenticateWithPassword(user_id, password);

System.out.println("Is server - " + server + " Authenticated? " + isAuthenticated);

if (isAuthenticated == false)
    throw new IOException("Authentication failed.");

ch.ethz.ssh2.Session sess = conn.openSession();
String new_commands = "";

for (int i = 0; i < commands.size(); i++) {
    new_commands = new_commands + commands.get(i) + "\n";
}

System.out.println("The command executed is: " + new_commands);

sess.requestDumbPTY();
sess.execCommand(new_commands);
InputStream stdout = new StreamGobbler(sess.getStdout());
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stdout));
InputStream errStrm = new StreamGobbler(sess.getStderr());
BufferedReader stderrRdr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(errStrm));
sess.getStdin().write("EXIT\n".getBytes());

System.out.println("the output of the command is");

while (true) {
    String line_out = br.readLine();
    if (line_out == null) {
        break;
    } else {
        System.out.println(line_out);
        output_logs.add(line_out);
    }
}

while (true) {
    String line_error = stderrRdr.readLine();
    if (line_error == null) {
        break;
    } else {
        System.out.println(line_error);
        output_logs.add(line_error);
    }
}

output_logs.add("Exit Code:" + sess.getExitStatus());
System.out.println("ExitCode: " + sess.getExitSignal());

sess.close();
conn.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

found a simple solution on the OS:
comment out the Cipher line in /etc/ssh/sshd_config
and run service sshd restart